# Why threads from ThreadPool don't run asynchronously?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, asynchronous, threadpool

I wrote the following proof-of-concept code:

```
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

class Maybe:
    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None
        self._exists = False
    def exists(self):
        return self._exists
    def value(self):
        if not self.exists():
            raise ValueError("Maybe doesn't hold any value")
        return self._value
    def set(self, value):
        self._value = value
        self._exists = True
    def unset(self):
        self._value = None
        self._exists = False

class Future(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._holder = Maybe()
        self._handler = None

    def _set(self, value):
        self._holder.set(value)
        self._invoke()

    def _invoke(self):
        if self._handler and self._holder.exists():
            self._handler(self._holder.value())

    def then(self, handler):
        self._handler = handler
        self._invoke()


def fib(count):
    f,s = 0,1
    for i in xrange(count):
        f,s =s,f+s
    return s

pool = ThreadPool(5)

def test(fun, arg):
    def print_fib(x):
        print("fib => {0}, {1}\n".format(arg, len(str(x))))
    tb = time.time()
    future = Future()
    future.then(print_fib)
    future._async_result = pool.apply_async(fun, [arg], callback=future._set)
    ta = time.time()
    print ("Time elapsed : {0}".format(ta - tb))
    return future


x1=test(fib, 2029)
x2=test(fib, 989999)
x3=test(fib, 103)
x4=test(fib, 38484)
x5=test(fib, 20)

time.sleep(3)
```

And I'm expecting all the calls to run asynchronously. But they don't seem to run asynchronously. For example, the call with `103` argument is expected to finish before the one with `989999` as argument. I don't see that happening. Even the first call takes more time if I use bigger argument for the second call.

Could anybody explain what is going on? Why do they not run asynchronously?

Comment: What output do you get? How do you know what finished first?

Comment: @user2357112: see the callback called `print_fib`. That tells me which one finished first, etc.

Comment: Please paste the output you get into the question. How long does the program take in all to finish?

Comment: @JanneKarila: The call with `103` argument is finished after the call with `989999`. Even if I increase the latter to `98999900`, the call with `103` doesn't finish first. They're getting printed in the order in which they're called.

Comment: I never see the result of 989999 because it takes 170 s to compute and the program exits after 3 s. All elapsed times printed are approximately zero.

Comment: @JanneKarila: make it `98999` instead, and see. Or increase the sleep time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `ThreadPool` sets all threads as daemons, i.e. if the main thread exits all threads will be terminated. `time.sleep(3)` is not enough for your process to finish its tasks and that's the cause. Note that your "time elapsed" log is not correct, because it measures time needed to fire a thread, not the actual task.

You should always `.join` threads. With `ThreadPool` you can do that with this piece of code:

```
...

x1=test(fib, 2029)
x2=test(fib, 989999)
x3=test(fib, 103)
x4=test(fib, 38484)
x5=test(fib, 20)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Also move all logs to `print_fib` function and it should work as expected.

Comment: *"Note that your "time elapsed" log is not correct, because it measures time needed to fire a thread, not the actual task."*. Yes, I know that, the elapsed is not the actual task. It is supposed to give me the time needed to fire a thread. That is what it is intended for.

Comment: @Nawaz Fair enough. Still it should work once you add `.close()` and `.join()`.

Comment: what do they do, especially `close()`? Can I call `test(fib, 231)` after I wrote them?

Comment: @Nawaz `.close()` notifies the pool that it should not accept more tasks. `.join()` simply waits for all threads to finish current tasks. Threads in ThreadPool are just infinite loops that wait for a task from a (thread-safe) queue. You have to call `.close()` in order to tell them "hey, stop waiting for tasks" so that each thread can exit (and thus you can `.join()` them).

Comment: @Nawaz You can't add tasks to the pool after calling `.close()`. If you want to do that, then you have to follow falsetru's idea or implement your own ThreadPool (not difficult at all).

Answer (score 1):

The threads are run concurrenly. But `fib` run too quickly; So it's hard to tell whether they're run concurrently. (except `fib(989999)`)

Try following instead (I moved elapsed time print part to `print_fib` to correctly print the elapsed time.):

```
def test(fun, arg):
    def print_fib(x):
        print("fib => {0}, {1}\n".format(arg, len(str(x))))
        ta = time.time()
        print ("Time elapsed : {0}".format(ta - tb))
    tb = time.time()
    future = Future()
    future.then(print_fib)
    future._async_result = pool.apply_async(fun, [arg], callback=future._set)
    return future

x1 = test(time.sleep, 2)
x2 = test(time.sleep, 5)
x3 = test(time.sleep, 1)
x4 = test(time.sleep, 4)
x5 = test(time.sleep, 3)

#time.sleep(10)

x1._async_result.get()
x2._async_result.get()
x3._async_result.get()
x4._async_result.get()
x5._async_result.get()
```

output:

```
fib => 1, 4

Time elapsed : 1.00200009346
fib => 2, 4

Time elapsed : 2.00099992752
fib => 3, 4

Time elapsed : 3.00200009346
fib => 4, 4

Time elapsed : 4.00200009346
fib => 5, 4

Time elapsed : 5.00200009346
```